# What will happen if I tap "Fix Now" in Device Maintenance?

Tags: samsung, settings

In **Settings > Device Maintenance**, Android says that I can tap <kbd>Fix Now</kbd> to improve my tablet's maintenance status.  **What is Android actually going to do when I tap <kbd>Fix Now</kbd>?**

I don't want to press it until I know what it is going to do.  I'm running Android 7.1.1 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017).

[image: device]

Answer (score 0):

Details from [app manual](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1041684984.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiww9vG4MjYAhUDL48KHYveDwUQFgg_MAM&usg=AOvVaw2GRQvA8ovJyB2aAlRp26iG)

> View the status of your device’s battery, 
>   storage, memory, and device security. You 
>   can also automatically optimize your device’s system resources

Further, it says *optimise* instead of *fix*

> Quick Optimization
>
> The quick optimization feature improves device 
>   performance through the following actions:
>
> • Identifying apps that use excessive battery power 
>   and clearing unneeded items from memory.
>
> • Deleting unnecessary files and closing apps running 
>   in the background.
>
> • Scanning for malware.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I tell if I'm indeed running that app?

Comment: What else can you be running when you click it. Not understood.Incidentally Google says that Samsung has moved this app as standalone app in play store for Samsung devices. Didn't check that since your device had this built-in.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my device has it built in because I access it simply by Settings > Device Maintenance.

Comment: Yes. That's what the manual says too.Besides, if you have grounds for suspecting if that is actually running , that could be a different question.

Comment: You can run it and see what it does and add your answer if it varies from what the manual says as posted.

Comment: We're you able to check?